# correlations for different variables and correlation matrix

Tags: correlation, matrix, pearson-r

I have a continuous target variable and 40 independent variables - some of them are ordinal, some are binary (Yes/No). When creating a correlation matrix I get correlations between:

1. continuous and ordinal variables,
2. between continuous and binary,
3. binary and binary,
4. ordinal and ordinal.

I have household level data: the target is income, and the independent variables are: language literacy (yes/no), education level (no education, primary, secondary, above secondary)  and median household income.
My objective is to control correlations between the target and the independent variables, and only between the independent variables and eventually create a model.
Is it fine to apply Pearsonr to all of them? I read around of point biserial and Spearman correlations, but documentations are very confusing, same do papers.
Overall, I understand that they all derive from the same formula simplified if data are not continuous. Indeed if I calculate pearsonr and point biterial correlations the coefficients and the p-values are exactly the same.
Could you help?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Vicky.  Mathematically you can do this.  All that's required is to encode your variables as numbers somehow.  Whether it's meaningful or helpful is another matter that depends on what you are trying to accomplish statistically.  Could you include some context and objectives in an edit to this post?

Comment: Thank you @whuber. :) I added some more context. Looking forward to your help.

Comment: Chances are the specific computation of the correlation matrix has no implications on the modelling later, other than for exploratory purposes? If I were you I'd probably ruthlessly compute a Pearson correlation matrix to have a look and get a rough impression, however I wouldn't later present it (as it can well be criticised for being inappropriate for the non-continuous variables) or base any other than very rough conclusions on it ("var X is clearly correlated with var Y"). If the matrix is meant to play a stronger role in your analysis, more care is needed.

Comment: Hi @ChristianHennig thanks for the comment, yes it's for explanatory purposes. What I don't understand is why if I calculate both point biserial and pearsonr, results are exactly the same (also python documentation underlines that they bring the same results), but then it is suggested for non continuous variables to use different type of correlations. There are inconsistencies between documentations and no coherent explanation. Is it about assumptions on the tests?

Comment: Standard point biserial correlation and Pearson correlation are mathematically equivalent. I can't comment on the difference in terminology, but the standard way to introduce Pearson and its theory is for continuous variables, and maybe some people thought that they need to use a different name in order to acknowledge that the situation with a categorical variable is different.

Comment: Agreed with all of @Christian's remarks.  For initial exploration, I would automatically use the logarithms of the incomes if possible.  If some are zero, then as a quick and dirty approach one could use a small root -- the cube root is good -- with a similar effect.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ChristianHennig very clear. I now found phi-k correlation which could be used for all types of variables, excluding continuous. Could this give a rough impression as well? I added a relevant question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605875/how-do-we-interprete-the-significance-of-the-phi-k-correlation-coefficients-in-p